# PHP- Display data in textarea

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

My goal is to display all emails inside a text area.

```
<?php 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `Clients`";
$userData = mysql_query($q);

while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData)){
    echo $user['Email'];
}
?>
```

it should echo all info into here:

```
<input type="text" name="text" >
```

I get the information fine from the DB, but im not sure how to echo the ALL the data into a SINGLE text field..

Comment: Add a text field maybe?

Comment: `echo "<textarea>"; while() {...` `...} echo "</textarea>";`?

Comment: <?php while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData)){
                               $temVal .=  $user['Email'];
                        }         ?> <input type="text" value="<?php  echo $temVal; ?>" />

Comment: Also, just an FYI, "text area" is not the same as a "text input". Your title says "text area" but your code says "input". `<textarea>` vs `<input type="text">`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do in following manner:-

```
<?php 
$q = "SELECT * FROM `Clients`";
$userData = mysql_query($q);
$email = array(); // create an array
  while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData)){
       $email[] =  $user['Email']; // assign each email to that array
  }
?>

<textarea><?php echo implode(','$email);?></textarea> // implode the array by `,` now all emails will show wiith `,` seperation.
```

Note:- this is the way how you need to do. Checking variables and do the necessary changes is on you. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

PHP Code

```
$userData = mysql_query($q);
$userEmails = array();
while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($userData)){
    $userEmails[] = $user['Email'];
}
```

HTML (example with a comma separated email string)

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo implode(', ', $userEmails); ?>" />
```